# Getting assemble-middleware-permalinks working

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, permalinks, assemble

I am trying to get the `assemble-middleware-permalinks` working on a build, but it doesn't really appear to work the way I want it to.

I have the following in my `Gruntfile.coffee`:

```
assemble:
  options:
    layout: 'default.hbs'
    layoutdir: '<%= config.app %>/_layouts'
    partials: '<%= config.app %>/_partials/*.hbs'
    plugins: ['assemble-middleware-permalinks']
    permalinks:
      preset: 'pretty'
  pages:
    files:
      '.tmp/': ['<%= config.app %>/pages/{,*/}*.hbs']
```

However when running the `grunt assemble` task, it still shows that it is only generating the following:

```
Running "assemble:pages" (assemble) task

  writing .tmp/about.html
  writing .tmp/index.html
  assembled 2 files OK
```

I have the `grunt-assemble` package installed which uses the 0.5.0 branch of assemble.

I have also tried manually putting in the structure instead of using the preset:

```
permalinks:
  structure: ':basename/index.html'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?